# Epoch timestamp in Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

The following is working:

```
responses/desc/50000/1/1525756206/json?X-apikey=542c0603951a208c4be688002d36f48808c40116174
```

But not this:

```
responses/desc/50000/1/@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')}/json?X-apikey=542c0603951a208c4be688002d3c40116174
```

Even this is not working:

```
responses/desc/50000/1/@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), '%s')}/json?X-apikey=542c0603951a208c4be688002d3c40116174
```

So it is 
`@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')}`
vs
`1525756206`
vs
`@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), '%s')}`

Can anybody help me here? I have been stuck here for a couple of days. How to calculate or use seconds in data factory?

Basically when I am using `@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')}`, It just ignore the filters/tag in the URL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally used the below to compute & use the epoch timestamp as a dynamic parameter.

```
@{div(sub(ticks(adddays(utcNow(), -1)), ticks('1970-01-01')),10000000)}
```

Courtesy: Azure Data factory Product team

Comment: Can anyone help me with, how to do this in azure data factory - data flow expression builder ?

Answer (score 1):

The expression works for me, but some format specifier are not available. You can find supported format specifier in this doc: [custom-date-and-time-format-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

And `formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), '%s')` will only show the second number, you can try `formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(), -6), 's')` if you want to show time in this format: 2018-05-16T07:55:18. (reference: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) )